# How to get file names of files updated by commit in GitHub Actions?

Tags: git, github, github-actions

In a GitHub Actions workflow, we tried multiple times to get the file names of the files changed by the pushed commit with this command `run: git diff-tree --no-commit-id --name-only -r ${{ github.sha }}`. But it always returns only the following log not giving a file name or a file name with path. See the below image.

[image: GitHub Actions run log]

**About Runner type**: `ubuntu-latest`, which is not a self-hosted runner.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The checkout action creates a shallow clone by default. Use

```
  - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    with:
      # Number of commits to fetch. 0 indicates all history for all branches and tags.
      # Default: 1
      fetch-depth: 2
```

source: https://github.com/actions/checkout#usage